# Where to get image io package?

Tags: java, image, io

Where do I get the api for imageIO?

So That i can use functions like

```
String imagePath = "C:/programs/";
    File inFile = new File(imagePath, "single image.gif");
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(inFile);
```

I plan on exporting this : import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

Answer (score 3):

It's in the JDK. Simply:

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
```

Comment: Or more to the point, it is in client **JREs** that are not obsolete (it was included in Java 1.4).  And a tip to the OP when using classes. Check the 'since' tag from the JavaDocs for the package/class or method.  E.G. http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html ('since' is listed at page bottom - with no anchor - grrr).

Answer (score 0):

finnw is correct about the API. However, what do you want to do with the BufferedImage? If you want it on a JLabel or as the icon for JOptionPane.showXXXDialog(), swing offers a good solution - class ImageIcon. Easy construction and use, IMO. Regards, - M.S.